# Peculiar use of C macros

Tags: c, enums, constants, preprocessor

Reading the code of the C library's sockets interface, I found this:

```
/* Types of sockets.  */
enum __socket_type
{
   SOCK_STREAM = 1,     /* Sequenced, reliable, connection-based
               byte streams.  */
#define SOCK_STREAM SOCK_STREAM
   SOCK_DGRAM = 2,      /* Connectionless, unreliable datagrams
               of fixed maximum length.  */
#define SOCK_DGRAM SOCK_DGRAM
...
```

This "idiom" is used all over bits/socket.h. I am just curious, what is the purpose of those macros?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These constants used to just be `#define`s, so what you're seeing is probably there to protect you from accidentally mixing old and new header files.  An advantage of using `enum` to define the constants is that `enum` members tend to be available in the debugger, and `#define` macros don't.

If you were to (accidentally) include some other header file that also tries to `#define SOCK_STREAM`, you would get a compiler warning instead of silently using a possibly incorrect value.

#### UPDATE

Looking through a [glibc git repo](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/commit/5b82669229ad4e39c6ba1467045a2d81d44b8ccc?f=bits/socket.h), I found the specific commit that added the `#define`s, with this comment:

```
* sysdeps/generic/socketbits.h: Also make SOCK_* constants available
as macros so that #ifdef works.
* sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/socketbits.h: Likewise.
```

There you have it.

Comment: Q: Isn't that what I said ;)?

Answer (score 1):

It's the C equivalent of an "enum".

The logical socket type "stream" (SOCK_STREAM) corresponds to the binary value "1".  A "datagram" (SOCK_DGRAM) is type "2".  Etc.

"Sockets" were invented before "enum" became part of the C language.

The above idiom  allows you to use "SOCK_STREAM" (for example) in your code; it also allows you to use "#ifndef SOCK_STREAM" (which might be significant in some legacy program).

Answer (score 0):

Historical systems used macros and didn't have such enums.

Older versions of POSIX/Single Unix (e.g. [SUSv3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html)) mandated that `SOCK_xxx` be macros. This means that these constants could be used in preprocessor directives (e.g. `#ifdef SOCK_DGRAM`). This could occasionally be useful to check at build time whether a system supported a non-standard socket type.

Newer standards (e.g. [SUSv4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html)) have relaxed this requirement on the system: the `SOCK_xxx` constants can be any kind of [symbolic constants](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_374). This includes preprocessor macros but also any other kind of definition that produces a constant expression (suitable for static initializers and other contexts that require a constant expression), such as enum constants.

The implementation you're looking at complies with SUSv3 (and SUSv4, SUSv3 compliance implies SUSv4 compliance in this respect). An implementation that only defined the enum and not the constants would be compliant with SUSv4 but not SUSv3.

The advantage of defining an enum is that it allows a compiler to give decent feedback if a `SOCK_xxx` constant is used in a context that doesn't call for one or if an arbitrary integer is used where a `SOCK_xxx` value is expected.

The same goes for many similar sets of constants.